# admin ajax is not working for non logged in users

Tags: ajax, users

I know that this issue has been discussed many times, but I think I tried most of the advises.

This is my code:

```
$.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>', 
    {'action': 'load_posts',
     'offset': offset,
     'author' : <?php echo $uid?>,
     'cat'  : '<?php echo $category->name?>',
     'color': '<?php echo get_cat_color($category->cat_ID)?>' 
    },  function(response){
        if (response.trim() == ""){$("#more_posts_<?php echo $catNoSpace?>").hide();}
           $("#cat<?php echo $catNoSpace?>").append("<div class='newdiv'>" + response + "</div>");
        }
```

And I have these both lines:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts', 'ng_load_posts');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts', 'ng_load_posts');
```

And a well working `ng_load_posts()` function.

Also I tried to disable all of my installed plugins.

What am I missing?

Comment: What response _precisely_ do you get for not logged in users?

Comment: I get a blank page with no specific error I can catch

Comment: _Completely_ blank, as in zero length content? `WP_DEBUG` enabled?

Comment: Even if I get something, how can I catch it? 
in console it is blank.
yes the wp_debug is enabled
May I send you additional info in private?

Comment: You can see the body of Ajax responses using browser's dev tools. Nope, private isn't considered appropriate here.

Comment: I get 302 in the admin-ajax request (when i check the Network panel).
the link is:
http://geektimecomv2.wpengine.com/author/avi/ 
and click on more posts below the first 4 posts on the righ

Comment: Wpengine caches everything for non logged in users, have you verified it's not a wpengine issue?

Comment: Nope, in staging (no-cache at all what so ever) it still happening.

Comment: Same issues after wordpress 4.0 upgrade.

[http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160561/front-end-ajax-login-form-broken-after-wp4-0-upgrade][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160561/front-end-ajax-login-form-broken-after-wp4-0-upgrade

Comment: have you tried `site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'` instead of `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`?

Answer (score 0):

There are some "magic" request parameters that are better avoided, mostly anything that can be used as a parameter name at a request url but also some more like "email" (don't think it is well documented and a quick google failed to bring a good reference).

Try to change the names of your parameters especially the "author" and "cat", maybe just add some prefix to them.

Comment: Thank you, Changed to bauthor and bcat and still nothing.

Comment: before making ajax event, enable console log in chrome for errros. And also change '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>' to '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ) ?>'. Try this luck!